# Why does this Swift struct require "mutating"?

Tags: swift, immutability

I am missing something about the mutability concept in Swift. I normally use objects, not structs, to get observability, so the value semantics are still new to me.

```
struct Game {
  var map: [[Int]]
```

So here I have declared `map` as mutable. So why in a method like this...

```
  mutating func createPlayer() {
    // emptyLocation -> (Int, Int)
    let (X,Y) = emptyLocation()
    map[X][Y] = .player
  }
```

...do I have to use the mutating? Yes, the function is mutating, but the original struct is declared as such. It seems that practically every `func` will be `mutating`in practice, which seems to defeat the purpose of the markup.

Is there some other way I should be doing this? Is the common use of `mutating` indicating a performance/memory issue I should be avoiding?

**Update:** I was rather upset at the way the internal state of the struct "leaked out" to the surrounding code; if you declare a member `var` inside the struct then it has to be outside as well, even if you never changed. This violates every concept of encapsulation I can think of. So I changed `struct` to `class`, removed all the `mutating`, and was done with it. I get the idea, but I'm not sure I fully understand the implementation. It seems, to this Swift-noob, that the `mutating` is something the compiler can determine without me telling it - is the member declared `var`?, does the func actually mutate it? etc.

Comment: If you change any property in a value type, the value type changes, hence the mutating keyword.

Comment: @J.Doe - I get that, but as the original "object" is declared var, what is the purpose of declaring mutating? The system already knows I declared it mutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is the default behaviour for a `struct` or `enum` that instance methods can not modify a property since they are value type. So you need to use `mutating` to override this behaviour.

The way you define your property, var or let, is still relevant for if you can change it from a mutable instance method or directly or not.

Since your property is not private you can still do

```
var g = Game(map: [[1]])
g.map.append([2])
```

Comment: What I'm finding is that the mutability sort of "leaks out" into the surrounding code. In this case, you cant do a let g =Game(), it HAS to be var g=Game(), which seems to violation encapsulation.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz True but you might be better of with a class then, structs are good tools for sure but they are simpler, for good and bad, than classes.

Comment: Adding `var` here does not violate encapsulation for a value type. The point of a value type is that the caller is fully aware of its mutation and that the mutation is not implicitly shared between scopes. Saying `let` on a value type implies "this will not change." So it is up to you to mark the places where it does change (so that those methods cannot be called on a `let` value).

Answer (score 1):

In Swift structs have value semantics, ie they behave as if they are values even though some of them like `String` and `Array` are implemented as references for performance reasons.  When you mutate such a struct the compiler may actually have to make a copy if you are not the only owner of the struct; this is known as copy on write and it is the possible performance issue that mutating indicates.

Comment: So is there some other implementation I should be using to avoid these COW, or is this just the way it is?

Comment: Generally its not an issue, but when it is an issue and you really do want reference semantics instead (ie shared ownership), use a reference type such as NSArray instead of the value semantic type (Array).